# Word Macro: Import/format images from folder & delete extra pages

Tags: vba, ms-word, page-break

I'm completely new to macros and I'm trying to do the following:

Import all images from a folder on the harddrive into a Word file - each having its own page and being resized to fill the page (A4 portrait) while still keeping its ratio.

I already managed to do the "import" part with each image gettings its own page with this code:

```
Sub BilderImport()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Img As Object
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim f As Object
    Dim fc As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fsize As Integer

    Path = "C:\tmp"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(Path)
    Set ff = f.Files
    i = 0
    fsize = ff.Count

    For Each Img In ff
        If Right(Img.Name, 4) = ".bmp" Or Right(Img.Name, 4) = ".jpg" Or Right(Img.Name, 4) = ".gif" Or Right(Img.Name, 4) = ".png" Then
            i = i + 1
            Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=Img 

            Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak 'Add file name below every img
            Selection.TypeText Text:=Img.Name

            If i < fsize Then 'No line break after the last img
                Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak 'Inserts line break after every img
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

A problem I've now come across: Word also adds a line break after every image and if an image is already pretty tall, this line break jumps to the next page, which adds an extra empty page because of the break I already add.

How do I prevent that or check for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub BilderImport()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim ff As Variant
    Dim Img As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim fsize As Long

    Path = "C:\tmp"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ff = fs.GetFolder(Path).Files
    i = 0
    fsize = ff.Count
    With ActiveDocument
        For Each Img In ff
            Select Case Right(Img.Name, 4)
                Case ".bmp", ".jpg", ".gif", ".png"
                    i = i + 1
                    .Characters.Last.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=Img
                    .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(11) & Img.Name & Chr(12)                End Select
        Next
        'No page break after last pic
        .Characters.Last.Previous.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your solution does indeed work, thanks! What exactly does "Chr(12)" add?  Sorry, I forgot to add my change to the code before (I'm inserting the file name below each img - I edited the first post) and if I just add `.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak ` and `Selection.TypeText Text:=Img.Name` now, it doesn't work anymore. How do I add this to your version?

Comment: @Neph Chr(12) inserts a manual page break. Instead of .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(12)
you could use .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(11) & Img.Name & Chr(12). However, if the image fills the page, your image name will still be on the next page - you will need to reduce the image size.

Comment: I see. I used your code: After `Case ".bmp", ".jpg", ".gif", ".png"`: 1) Increment i, 2) AddPicture, 3) Chr(11), 4) Img.Name, 5) Chr(12). But this outputs every file name and the first image on the first page, then one image per page (without name) with the additional blank pages not being deleted. I think I'll try the idea I posted below majka's answer (unless there's an easier way) but first I want to get this to run.

Comment: You need to pay closer attention to what I advised: .Characters.Last.InsertBefore Chr(11) & Img.Name & Chr(12) is *all one line of code*.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm completely new to macros/VBA and thought you meant "just use these three in this order". This solution works, thanks! I'm guessing `Chr(11)` is the line break then, right? Could you please edit your answer to fit the edited question.

Comment: Done. And, yes, Chr(11) is a line break.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches how to solve it. I would prefer a combination of both:

- If you are resizing the images, resize them just a bit smaller (accounting for the extra line break)
- set the font size to 0 or 1 and set paragraph to tiny line height before adding the pictures

Depending on the image size, the second point would be enough.

There is the third possibility: You would have to check the page count before entering the image and after. But this would slow the whole macro down.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! 1. No, I don't resize them, Word does a pretty good job on its own. 2. Sorry, forgot to add that (I'll edit the first post) I want to add the file name below every image, so I can't change the font size. 3. I see. Yes, if I add 50+ images, this would indeed get slower. An idea: Set the bottom margin to a higher value (e.g. 1cm more), then add the images and change the bottom margin back to the original value. Hence, the tall images would be smaller and should leave enough space for the file name. Would this work or make the macro a lot slower?